# Silverlight or MVC.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Its time to rebuild my portfolio site, and I am thinking of either using Silverlight (still have to learn the basics but would be fun) or use MVC.NET.

I would like to use Silverlight since its something I am really interested in learning, and building up a small portfolio site should not be an out of this world task.  However I do not know if its advisable, since I want my portfolio to be viewed and accessed by everyone, platform independent.

What do you guys think?

Thanks

Comment: @johann cheers for your try if your option is silverlight....

Answer (score 5):

From an SEO and ease of page bookmarking point of view you might want to go with traditional HTML, i.e. ASP.NET MVC.

The downside of building an entire site in Flash or Silverlight is that users can't bookmark a specific page within it, and search engine bots can't by default follow links or parse the text.

The following page deals with SEO and Silverlight sites.

http://silverlight.net/learn/whitepapers/seo-for-silverlight/

Comment: Take a look at the System.Windows.Controls.Frame and System.Windows.Navigation.UriMapper classes. These allow page bookmarking just fine.

Comment: @crimson13: Yes, but developer effort is required to achieve this. With a regular HTML site you get bookmarking out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If really want platform independence you should avoid Silverlight, users on Linux especially won't get a good experience at the moment.

However if you want reasonable access by people in general then Silverlight is do-able.

You might ask yourself whether coupling your important portfolio site with your own personal improvement plan is a good idea.

Utlimately then develop your site with ASP.NET-MVC then spend some time with Silverlight without impacting your site,  or perhaps include some content via Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can build both of them. It will allow you to see the differences between them and compare them.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  I think I will go for MVC.NET, and then try to emulate the same in Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

I think your portfolio site should show your works also with its structure. If you are doing design, It would be nicer to make your site with Silverlight!

Answer (score 0):

Those are actually not two techonologies that are related in any way or say that you should use one over another. You can have a ASP.NET MVC site (which I prefer and suggest to you) and then use Silverlight parts in it.

I prefer using Silverlight (or Flash for the same matter) only for animations, maybe parts of a website but not for entire website.  If only portfolio will be built in Silverlight you should definitely do it in classic HTML too for users that lack Silverlight support.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late about answering.

Now, Silverlight seems to go to its end. Microsoft wants to stop supporting it after 2021.

But, since Microsoft says they will ever support OOB mode, I think you could continue to developp to Silverlight today.

So I think, it's up not for animations. It's up to users of the application :
Silverlight has some good avaibilities to simulate windows like application.
After loading data in cache, you can have better user reactivity.

And, you get an other good point : user can easily cancel data they write.

At the end, with RIA services technology, for developpers, this is pretty easy to simulate entities like in client development.

As it says before, you can have mvc web application with silverlight inside.